# Indexing with biblatex - how to filter out publication titles of indexed authors?

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I am creating an index with biblatex, but want to filter out the publication titles.
The goal is to have only the names of the authors in the index of authors, right now I end up with all author entries as desired but the titles of their books or articles create additional entries in the index file. How to surpress these listing?

MWE would be as follows:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,
12pt,
twoside,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\bibliography.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[split,makeindex]{splitidx}
\newindex[List of authors]{aut}
\usepackage[%bibencoding=utf8,
backend=bibtex8, 
natbib=true,
style=authoryear-icomp,
maxnames=3, minnames=1,
sorting=nyt,
indexing=true,
abbreviate=false,
dashed=true,
eprint=false,
block=none,
%bibencoding=auto
]{biblatex}
%
\begin{document}
The example is really short MWE \parencite{article}. Maybe something is missing, please correct me if I forgot something as mentioned by \textcite{book}.
%
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Additional question would be (I left it out of the MWE):

In the current form, everybody is indexed that ist cited in the text.
The publisher I am preparing the book for would like to have only names of authors indexed that are cited in the main text:

How to filter out authors from the index that are cited in footnotes?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. There is a `\addbibresource` missing and the `\bibliography` in the filecontents command looks quite fishy. Beside this: I would redefine the `\citeindex` and `bibindex` macros (the original are in biblatex.def).

Comment: @Mario,the text does not deal with indexing at all, although helpfull in general it does not tackle my problem.

Comment: @Ulrike
Thank you but I remain confused: 1. the bib file entries I simply copy and pasted from another MWE that featured biblatex. What exactly is fishy other than that the entries are obviously made up and rather incomplete?

Comment: You are using the command `\bibliography` in the argument of filecontents. What filename do you think will it expand to? Did you actually try your example?

Comment: @Ulrike
so changing 
`\begin{filecontents}{\bibliography.bib}`

to

`\begin{filecontents}{\mybib.bib}`

and adding a

`\bibliography{mybib.bib}

Comment: @Ulrike
so changing 
`\begin{filecontents}{\bibliography.bib}`

to

`\begin{filecontents}{\mybib.bib}`

and adding a

`\bibliography{mybib.bib}`

make it work? I simpy do not have the knowledge to mimic a working bibliography (or file contents) for a MWE , so copied and pasted one where nobody (apparently) complained. I am sorry, I still hope the question is still clear enough to get an answer. I found the biblatex manual not very instructive regarding indexing options.

Comment: The second argument of `\begin{filecontents}` provides the name the filecontents will be written to.  So you want `\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}` if you are going to use `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` (it is important to note that there is *not* a `\ ` before `bibliography.bib`).  Another possibility is `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}`, where `\jobname` will expand to 'the same file name as the current `.tex` file; then you could use `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` which is the same as `\addbibresource{<nameofcurrenttexfile>.bib}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three examples (20-22) from the biblatex documentation demonstrate:

1. a single index with `makeidx`,
2. multiple indices with `index`, and
3. multilevel indices with `imakeidx`.

To create a single index of authors cited inline, just load biblatex with `indexing=cite` and redefine the `citeindex` bibliography macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteindex} and not test {\iffootnote} }
    {\indexnames{author}}{}}
```

When the author list is missing you may wish to index editors or translators instead. To do this, replace `author` with `labelname`.

Here's an example demonstrating two indices - one for authors and another for titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,maxnames=3,backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[List of authors]{author}
\newindex[List of Titles]{title}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\sindex[author]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\sindex[title]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteindex} and not test {\iffootnote} }
    {\indexnames{author}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler \parencite{aksin,companion}. Filler.\footcite{bertram}
\Textcite{markey,jaffe}...
\printbibliography
\printindex*
\end{document}
```

Saving this document as `test.tex`, it can be compiled with:

```
latex test
bibtex test
latex test
latex test
splitindex.pl test
latex test
```

Comment: That looks really promising, thank you so much.

But I have problems compiling it, it may have to do with a language setting as it gives me the warning:
! Textline contains invalid character

With splitindex this problem never occured.

Comment: The final log on my end is warning-free with the latest release of biblatex. We improved the indexing macros in `biblatex.def` significantly in biblatex 2.3, so if you have an earlier version you should upgrade. Other than that I can't help troubleshoot without further details.