# Indexing with biblatex - names only

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I found it easy to produce an index from biblatex using the makeidx package, biblatex's indexing=cite option, and the \makeindex and \printindex commands. However, what I did not find easy was to have an index of names only, with no titles mentioned. Please have a look at the following MWE, which I take from the biblatex example documents (20), slightly adjusted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[indexing,style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{\indexnames{labelname}{}}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section*{Indexing with the \texttt{makeidx} package}

\nocite{*}

\cite{piccato,gaonkar,malinowski,coleridge,gerhardt,cicero}

\index{Example entry}

\clearpage


\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I tried to insert

```
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteindex} and not test {\iffootnote} }
    {\indexnames{author}}{}}
```

as proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111291/indexing-with-biblatex-how-to-filter-out-publication-titles-of-indexed-authors), but that doesn't seem to work. So, any ideas how I can get an index of names only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `indexing=cite` to your `biblatex` options.

```
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

To avoid `\citetitle` from adding the title to the index, you need to modify the `\citetitle` macro to change what it indexes. I've made the assumption that if you cite a title, you still want the author to appear on the index on that page, so I've modified `\citetitle` to index the authors' names. But if you don't want that you can just remove the indexing code altogether from `\citetitle`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\usepackage{makeidx}
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{\indexnames{labelname}{}}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section*{Indexing with the \texttt{makeidx} package}

\nocite{*}

\cite{piccato,gaonkar,malinowski,cicero}
\citetitle{coleridge,gerhardt}

\index{Example entry}

\clearpage


\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that actually solved the problem as described in my question. However, it left me with the following problem: The proposed \renewbibmacro* will not only allow names of authors to the index, but also titles of works, if they are cited after \citetitle in a footnote, like this: \footnote{\citetitle[43--72]{coleridge}. Any idea on why that is, and how to fix it? Obiously, I wouldn't want the titles of works in an index of names.

Comment: @faxminell I've updated the solution.