# Authorindex with natlib fixes do not work

Tags: xetex, natbib, authorindex

I want to use author index with natbib. An example below (with the fix of the author index package) does not work. The fix of [Index both authors and subjects with authorindex and makeindex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174379/index-both-authors-and-subjects-with-authorindex-and-makeindex) does not work either (with \cite the .idx and .ind files are empty and \aicite gives "Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.")

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{authorindex}
\let\cite=\aicite
\makeatletter
% natbib.cfg (copy/pasted from authorindex 2005/03/22 user manual)
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{authorindex}{%
  \ifNAT@numbers
    \let\org@@citex\NAT@citexnum
  \else
    \let\org@@citex\NAT@citex
  \fi
  \def\@citex[#1][#2]#3{%
    \typeout{indexing: [#1][#2]{#3}}%
    \org@@citex[#1][#2]{#3}%
    \@aicitey{#3}}%
  \renewcommand\NAT@wrout[5]{%
     \if@filesw{%
       \let\protect\noexpand\let~\relax
       \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\aibibcite{#5}{#1}}%
       \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#5}{{#1}{#2}{{#3}}{{#4}}}}}%
     \fi}}{}}
\renewcommand\NAT@index{\@bsphack\begingroup
   \def~{\string~}\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}}
\newcommand\NAT@myidxtxt{\NAT@name}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Infinite descent \cite{Fermat1659-DescInf}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\printauthorindex

\end{document}

xeLatex, bibtex, xeLatex, xeLatex works without authorindex
the following lines being commented out:
%%%\usepackage{authorindex}
%%%\let\cite=\aicite
%%%\printauthorindex

xeLatex produces the following error with authorindex after
\cite{Fermat1659-DescInf}:

Runaway argument?
]{Fermat1659-DescInf}\@aicitey {Fermat1659-DescInf} 
./authorindex-natbib.tex:27: Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.27 

%%% File authorindex-natbib.bib %%%
@unpublished{Fermat1659-DescInf,
   author =  {De Fermat, Pierre},
   title =   {Relation des nouvelles d\'ecouvertes en la science des nombres},
   month =   {August },
   year =    1659,
   note = {Lettre \`a {Pierre de Carcavi}},
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: \@citex has three arguments but authorindex assumes two in its own code. Are you stuck with natbib or would you consider to switch to biblatex/biber? See here for an example of an index: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377983/indexing-with-biblatex-names-only

Comment: It worked well with biblatex/bibte, hyperref, and indextools for multiple indexes EXCEPT that \begin{refsection} ... \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]\end{refsection} produces NO BIBLIOGRAPHY at all!

Comment: Did you run biber? What does the .blg-file say?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128196/problem-with-refsection says biber solves the problem and it does!