# Splitindex and authors citing

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx

why command `\cite{}` using [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) with `splitindex` option and [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with `indexing=cite` option causes

```
Package imakeidx Warning: Undefined index file `split' on input line 33.
```

After compiling my source file (`split.tex`) I somehow have two `.idx` files:
`split-persons.idx`:

```
\indexentry{Smith, Joe}{1}
\indexentry{Greenwild, Dirk}{1}
\indexentry{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry{Jordan, Peter}{1}
```

and `split.idx`:

```
\indexentry[persons]{Smith, Joe}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Greenwild, Dirk}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,indexing=cite]{biblatex} %for digital version 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage[truexindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=persons,program=truexindy,options=-M texindy]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
    author  = "Greenwild, Dirk",
    title   = "Yellow pages",
    year    = "1998",
}
@book{book2,
    author    = "Jordan, Peter",
    title     = "Math in the world",
    year      = "1996",
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}
    {\index[persons]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\begin{document}

Foo\index[persons]{Smith, Joe}.
Foo\cite{book1}. Jordan\index[persons]{Jordan, Peter} foo\cite{book2}.

\printindex[persons]
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**

If I add fake command `\makeindex[]` the warning disappears. Now I get also two `.idx` files after compilation. `split-persons.idx` is identical like before but `split.idx` now contains not only person records but also book titles records which goes to main index. That is the problem I think.
Content of the `split.idx` now:

```
\indexentry[persons]{Smith, Joe}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Greenwild, Dirk}{1}
\indexentry[split]{Yellow pages@\emph  {Yellow pages}}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry[split]{Math in the world@\emph  {Math in the world}}{1}
```

Comment: How do you compile your file, i.e. which commands do you run in which order? Can you please remove all auxiliary files and then re-run these steps and describe what you do and what happens.

Comment: `xelatex.exe  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "split".tex` for two times, then `biber.exe ""C:\Users\andzejc\Desktop\testsplitindex\split"` and two more times `xelatex.exe  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "split".tex`. After each command I have `Process exited normally`

Comment: Mhhh, I'm no index expert, but I assume that the involved indexing packages somehow assume that there is a generic index (i.e. one that is not called with an optional argument in `\index`). The MWE only defines a `persons` index and so the generic index is empty, leading to the warnings. I guess you can ignore these.

Comment: Yes, if I add to my code the fake command `\makeindex[]` this warning disappears. BTW there is absolutely no problem when just calling `Foo\index[persons]{Smith, Joe}`. The problem is only with `Foo\cite{book1` and `indexing=cite` option enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add `\makeindex`, the generated `.idx` file is

```
\indexentry[persons]{Smith, Joe}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Greenwild, Dirk}{1}
\indexentry[andc]{Yellow pages@\emph  {Yellow pages}}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry[persons]{Jordan, Peter}{1}
\indexentry[andc]{Math in the world@\emph  {Math in the world}}{1}
```

which means that `biblatex` adds also index entries for the titles. This is the reason for the warning: without `\makeindex`, there are tries to write in the default index file which can't succeed, because it is not defined.

Either fix it on the `biblatex` side or just add `\makeindex`.

Please, be aware that the preferred declaration for `biblatex` is

```
\addbibresource{<filename>.bib}
```

rather than `\bibliography{<filename>}` (note that `.bib` must the added in the preferred declaration style).

Comment: "Either fix it on the biblatex side or just add \makeindex." The second variant is clear. But how to implement your first suggestion "fix it on the biblatex side"? I think it is somewhat related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377983/indexing-with-biblatex-names-only) ant [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111291/indexing-with-biblatex-how-to-filter-out-publication-titles-of-indexed-authors).

Comment: @andc That warrants a new question, I guess.