# Biblatex and imakeidx to create indices of authors, terms, and titles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, memoir, indexing, imakeidx

I would like to create an *index of authors*, an *index of titles* and an *index of terms* using `biblatex` with `indexing=cite` and `imakeidx`.

However, I manage to get only an **Index of Authors**.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,indexing,indexing=cite,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

% add authors, editors, etc to list of authors
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteindex} and not test {\iffootnote} }
    {\indexnames{labelname}}{}}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=term,title=Index of Terms,columns=2]

\begin{document}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This \index[term]{book} is great! \cite{Knu86}

\printbibliography

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index of Authors}
\printindex
\printindex[term]

\end{document}
```

Usually `indexing` will give an index with both the authors and titles. `Indexing=cite` only authors. What is the easiest way possible in my example to get three indices?

Comment: Remove the `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` line, it does nothing in `biblatex`. It can only add confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [Indexing with biblatex - how to filter out publication titles of indexed authors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111291/35864) you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[indexing=cite, backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[program=texindy, name=nameindex, title = Index of names]
\makeindex[program=texindy, name=titleindex, title = Index of titles]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}
    {\index[nameindex]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titleindex]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteindex} and not test {\iffootnote} }
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}{}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{geer,worman,sigfridsson,cicero}
\index{foo}

\printbibliography
\printindex[nameindex]
\printindex[titleindex]
\printindex
\end{document}
```