# How to create two separate indices: Subject index and Index of Authors with BibLatex

Tags: biblatex, indexing

Generating separate (author and subject) indexes with bibtex is very well documented. But how about generating those two indexes with BibLatex, I found no documentation.

Comment: One practical example is in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/21-indexing-multiple.tex, but you can use other indexing tools than the one described there.

Comment: There is also http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/22-indexing-subentry.tex for `imakeidx`. Furthermore you may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111291/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121451/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397781/35864

Comment: Did any of the linked resources help you? Could you find a way to do what you want and would be willing to post an answer yourself so people can benefit from it was well? If the links didn't help, what did you try and how/why did it not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` comes with several example files, three of them concerned with indexing.

- [`20-indexing-single.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/20-indexing-single.tex)
- [`21-indexing-multiple.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/21-indexing-multiple.tex)
- [`22-indexing-subentry.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/22-indexing-subentry.tex)

Those files not only contain example code, but also extensive explanatory comments.

Here is a simplified version of `21-indexing-multiple.tex` that uses `imakeidx` (as `22-indexing-subentry.tex`).

The key is that one needs to define the standard `biblatex` indexing (bib)macros to call `\index` with an optional argument to specify into which index the entry should go.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, indexing]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=names,title={Names}]
\makeindex[name=titles,title={Titles}]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
   {\namepartfamily}
   {\namepartgiven}
   {\namepartprefix}
   {\namepartsuffix}}


\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer,pines}

\index{Example entry}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\printindex[names]
\printindex[titles]
\end{document}
```

[image: Index of Names]

[image: Index of Titles]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, here is an MMWE that creates the two distinct indexes (authors and subjects)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @article{sanchez16,
      title={Use of Damage Rating Index to Quantify Alkali-Silica Reaction Damage in Concrete: Fine versus Coarse Aggregate.},
      author={Sanchez, L. and Fournier, B. and Jolin, M. and Bedoya, M. and Bastien, J. and Duchesne, J.},
      journal={ACI Materials Journal},
      volume={113},
      number={4},
      year={2016}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=numeric,natbib=true,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt,refsegment=section,defernumbers=true,maxnames=4,indexing=cite
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{my.bib}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex
    \makeindex[name=names,title={Names}]
    \DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
      \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}
    \renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
      \ifciteindex
        {\indexnames{labelname}}
        {}}
    %++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    \begin{document}
    \citet{sanchez16} have shown    \index{Damage Rating}
    \printbibliography
    \printindex
    \printindex[names]
    \end{document}
```