# biblatex with index

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex and attempting to get an index of not only words but also authors. However, I do not want to see titles. The following MWE gives me titles in the index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@article{sanchez16,
  title={Use of Damage Rating Index to Quantify Alkali-Silica Reaction Damage in Concrete: Fine versus Coarse Aggregate.},
  author={Sanchez, L. and Fournier, B. and Jolin, M. },
  journal={ACI Materials Journal},
  volume={113},
  number={4},
  year={2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[style=numeric,natbib=true,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt,refsegment=section,defernumbers=true,maxnames=4,indexing=cite
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}
    \citet{sanchez16} have shown
    \index{Computer}
    \printbibliography
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make your example compilable by adding a few example `.bib` entries (or even better: using `biblatex-examples.bib`) and citing a few entries so that we can see what you are asking about. Please test the MWE you post here in a new, empty folder to see what we see when we compile the file.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `latexmk` if possible, this eschews the errors from insufficient many `latex` runs or some missing interim commands.

Answer (score 2):

Most citation commands call the bibmacro `citeindex` for indexing. The standard definition of that macro from `biblatex.def` is

```
\newbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}
```

If you want only names indexed, you can redefine this macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[style=numeric, natbib=true, backend=bibtex, sorting=nyt,
  indexing=cite]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \citet{sigfridsson} have shown
  \index{Computer}
  \printbibliography
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index without work title.]

Comment: Great, but now how to have two separate indexes (without modifying the latex file), one for subjects and another for authors?

Comment: @victor I don't understand what you mean by subjects, but maybe my answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507429/35864 can help you.